# I am having issues trying to select files from the drop down in Temporal Controller

Tags: qgis

[image: Dropdown field chooser not working]

I am trying to select a field in the temporal controller section but it does not work.

No matter what configuration I chose, the field drop down menu does not work.

I am trying to animate the path of a storm in the Pacific.  [Data file attached](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/international-best-track-archive-for-climate-stewardship-ibtracs/v04r00/access/shapefile/IBTrACS.ACTIVE.list.v04r00.lines.zip).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "date" fields that are of type `integer` as year, month, day, hour, etc... need to be placed in a `Date/Time` field. Luckily you have a field formatted properly but not in a Date/Time column so let's do that with the `ISO_TIME` field.

It's the `Date/Time` field type that will work with temporal manager.

So create a new field of `Date/Time` type.

Then format your time fields to this new field using the field calculator to update the new Date/Time field with:

`to_datetime("ISO_TIME", 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')`

Answer (score 0):

I can now see and chose the date field.

I added a new table it seems to work better.

```
to_datetime("ISO_TIME", 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')
```

and added it to my new field "datatime"